# How to call methods from other scripts in GAS without publishing as a library

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, scripting

Is there any way I can reference a method in one script in GAS from another without publishing my project as a library? I want to publish my entire set of code (my project) as one library, but I want to be able to call methods from one script within the project from another without having to publish the other as a library and reference it that way.

Comment: You could use `UrlFetchApp.fetch(Published Web App URL)` in the requesting Apps Script file and `doGet()` and/or `doPost()` to receive the request, process the request and return something in the Apps Script file that is your main hub.

Comment: Another option is Apps Script Execution API: https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/rest/